# Lua: attempt to compare boolean with number

Tags: lua

I came across an error: `attempt to compare boolean with number` with the following code:

```
local x = get_x_from_db() -- x maybe -2, -1 or integer like 12345
if 0 < x < 128 then
    -- do something
end
```

What causes this error? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`0 < x < 128` is equivalent to `(0 < x) < 128)`, hence the error message.

Write the test as `0 < x and x < 128`.

Answer (score 7):

writing `0 < x < 128` is okay in Python, but not in Lua.

So, when your code is executed, Lua will first calculate if `0 < x` is `true`. If it is true, then the comparison becomes `true < 128`, which is obviously the reason of the error message.

To make it work, you have to write:

```
if x < 128 and x > 0 then
  --do something
end
```