# Error in my Lua script: attempt to compare boolean with number

Tags: lua

I get the Following Error:

`SCRIPT ERROR: @esx_farmfisch/server/main.lua:34: attempt to compare boolean with number`

This is the Code where the Error Appears: http://prntscr.com/sbgirk

Comment: you can check any value to match the type: ` type(value)=="number" `

Comment: Either `koda.limit` or `koda.count` is a boolean value.

Comment: Possibly answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29646609/lua-attempt-to-compare-boolean-with-number). Also, please [paste your code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) as a snippet instead of a screenshot.